# Loopback: Atomic read and update

Tags: database, locking, increment, loopbackjs, acid

is there a way to implement something like this in loopback?

```
LOCK
 READ
 INCREMENT
UNLOCK
```

I would like to keep counters as database values, each key is a counter (or a setting), and they shouldn't accessed my multiple requests at the same time.

Also this should work for local requests too (no remoteHooks)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the mongoDB connector, this is supported by [extended operators](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/MongoDB+connector#MongoDBconnector-UsingMongoDBoperatorsinupdateoperations).

```
MyModel.updateAll(
  { id: 123' },
  { '$inc': { myproperty: 1 }}, // increment myproperty by 1
  { allowExtendedOperators: true }
);
```

Otherwise, you can use [transactions](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Using+database+transactions) as a workaround for some connectors.

Comment: Nope, does not work properly. The value is updated, but I cannot read the contents anywhere. Sure, I can fire up another request, but being async I cannot be sure if other requests have been sent in the meanwhile.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot read the contents anywhere ? And are you using extended operators or transactions ?

Comment: I'm using operators (mongo database), as soon as I tell the model to update all matching records it returns a count of updated records, but I don't know yet the value. I can read it afterwards, but again the atomicity is broken, because another operation might have been launched in the meanwhile.

Comment: ah yes that's a feature missing from the update. Sadly the MongoDB connector does not support this at the moment. Unless you're willing to switch DB, I don't see any solution here unless implementing yourself transactions in the loopback mongodb connector.